# How to generate 'UNA:+.?*'' the first line of EDI D960A format

Tags: c#, .net, edi

In EDI D960A format the first line is below

```
UNA:+.?*'
```

How to generate this line using EdiTools nuget package in C#.

I already this below line of code.

```
            var una = new EdiTools.EdiSegment("UNA");
            una[01] = ":+.?*";
            ediDocument.Segments.Add(una);
```

But upper code generate this line below

```
UNA>+.
```

Please suggest the possible code.

Comment: UNA is optional unless you use non standard seperators or escape characters